# Class styles are applied when attribute set manually but not dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I want to change the class name of a canvas dynamically (after a click) using javascript in my AngularJS application, for this I tried the following code :

```
submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
var cc = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="DashboardController"]')).scope().canvas;
cc = "chart chart-"+cc;
document.getElementById('mycanvas').className = cc;
},false);
```

The first query is to get the "cc" value, the second is to change the class name.

"mycanvas" 's class name is changed to the "cc" value (I checked that by inspecting the element) but the styles aren't applied !

For example, when I set the class manually to "chart chart-line", the chart appears, but it doesn't work dynamically.

Any ideas why and how ?

Comment: is submit is a buutton of type submit? and are you able to see new value of cc = "chart chart-"+cc;?

Comment: Yes, submit is a button of type submit, and I can see the new value of cc and it's correct, I can even see that the class name has changed to it (when I inspect the element in my browser), but still it's not working.

Comment: submit.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
event.preventDefault() then rest of the code

Comment: It didn't work :( the class name is still correct but nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an ng-click and append the new class you want.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="Controller.changeClass"></button>
```

Javascript:

```
vm.changeClass = function () {
    document.getElementById("mycanvas").className += "whateverClass";
};
```

Comment: Same thing, the class name is changed but the canvas isn't shown.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? If the class name in on the element, the corresponding styles should load.  How are you importing your styles?